# How to setup .NET EF Core Sqlite (SSMS) Project - jr. dev

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, ssms, entity-framework-core-migrations

I am new to Visual Studio btw (I use VSC but assumed I needed VS for this assessment due to sln file).

I am running into difficulties with setting up an existing .NET EF Core project and database. Once I get the project connected, EntityFramework is constantly broken and I only seem to be able to make changes to the database by manually adjusting the migrations as they always try to create a new table which conflicts with the existing table.

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Process I used to submit project:

1. Restore DB via BAK file.
2. Configure Connection string (which does pull the existing data).
3. Make changes to Domain Models and ViewModels.
4. Add Migration.
5. Update db (fails due to existing table).
6. Manually edit migration files.
7. Update db (succeeds).
8. Repeat 3 - 8 as needed.

Comment: Welcome to using EF (it's a lot of over-engineering for simple projects) I am trying to upgrade an older project at the moment and EF has been the biggest headache out of everything.

I would check the models match the DB tables exactly, datatype included. It's possible a migration was missed.

Also try connecting to a new db and seeing if the EF works consitently on that.

Comment: Also when making the upgrade vs running it, you may need to be running the project. I have had weird issues with it.

Comment: How are SSMS and Sqlite related?

Comment: @Slipoch I decided to convert to DB first approach as it was a headache. I got this as a tech assessment with no migration files for the existing DB, not sure if that contributes. Additionally, it had Domain-ViewModel (correct name?) architecture which I am new to, so I just switched off lol. Sorry for the delay, I appreciate your comment! As for connecting to a new DB, that works every time so not sure why I couldn't get it setup with an existing one, but it's done now so oh well.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Not sure, I am new to these products. As I said in my post, I'm a noob. I got the project as a tech assessment with Sqlite packages installed but also a .BAK file. I noticed .BAK can be restored in ssms so I used that, but DB Browser for Sqlite probably would have been better. The whole project structure was new to me and confused me. Either way, I resolved the issue by transitioning to DB first.

Comment: SSMS is sql management studio, it''as just an interface for writing sql queries and connecting to sql. You can view the table schemas etc.